# how to export data with date and foreign key

Tags: python, django, excel, database, export

Ive managed to export the required data. However, as for date, it gives me a string of number instead of date. Tried to use data_format but does not work. Also, I have a foreign key in the database which is studName. I want to export the student name instead of the id.  below is model code:

```
class Namelist(models.Model): 
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
program = models.CharField(max_length=10)
year = models.IntegerField(default=1)
studType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
courseType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
nationality = models.CharField(max_length=20)
VMSAcc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
classGrp = models.ForeignKey('GroupInfo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_day(self):
    return self.day

def get_time(self):
    return self.time


 class MarkAtt(models.Model):
studName = models.ForeignKey(Namelist,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
classGrp = models.ForeignKey(GroupInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
currentDate = models.DateField(default=now())
week = models.IntegerField(default=0)
attendance = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Below is my view code:

```
def export_users_xls(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="attendance.xls"'

wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('attendance') 
# Sheet header, first row
row_num = 0

font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font_style.font.bold = True
#date_format = xlwt.XFStyle()
#date_format.num_format_str = 'dd/mm/yyyy'

columns = ['id', 'Student Name', 'Class Group', 'Date','week', 'Attendance' ]

for col_num in range(len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style) # at 0 row 0 column 

# Sheet body, remaining rows
font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()


rows = MarkAtt.objects.all().values_list('id', 'studName', 'classGrp', 'currentDate', 'week', 'attendance')
for rowin rows:
    row_num += 1
    for col_num in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)


wb.save(response)

return response
```

The current exported data is:

id  studName    Class Group Date    week    Attendance

1   1   1   43713   1   1         1        1

2   2   1   43713   1   1         1         1

Instead of printing the student id, i would to retrieve the student name associated with the id. How can i do that? And how do i solve the date? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

### In django, the DateTimeField, and DateField subclass datetime.datetime()

you can use the datetime.datetime. methods to access year, month, minute, etc..

`query = MarkAtt.objects.filter(id=1)`

returns date in UNIX format:
`date = query.currentDate`

using month, day, and year methods that were inherited from datetime.datetime
returns date: 09-19-2019:
`formatted_date = '%s-%s-%s' % (date.month, date.day, date.year)`

### If you want to access foreign key related fields you can traverse:

`name = query.studName.name`
where studName is the related_name (by default it will be the same as the model field. You can overwrite this for more comprehensible logic, but thats all up to you.

`studName = models.ForeignKey(
    Namelist,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True, 
    default=None, 
    related_name='name_list'
)`

Now the query will become: `name = query.name_list.name`